# Safari 11.1.2 - Discord is not showing entire page or scaling correctly

Tags: macos, safari, websites

Now Discord is not scaling correctly or showing the entire page. I am using Safari 11.1.2

This comes after realizing I can't comment on YouTube or see the notifications on YouTube in Safari 11.1.2. I don't know if these two issues on Discord and YouTube are the result of the same problem.

It just seems like sites are breaking all of a sudden on Safari 11.1.2. But, I don't know if that is true. I tested this out in Firefox and I don't have the problem with that browser.

Comment: First thing to do is check with another browser like Firefox (my preferred), Chrome (not so much), Edge, Brave, Opera, etc.  If it happens in another browser, then it may be that particular discord server and not your Safari.

Comment: It's important to put what you've already tested and the results in the original question.  Now as to the question itself - you're just looking for a "verification?"  How will that go to solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue with Discord and Safari 11.1.2.  It started a few days ago.  Chrome does not have this issue.